# accessing structure's member by using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I compiled the code below on gcc(x64).

Why can I access the structure items by putting dot(people[0].name) rather than '->'?

Isn't people[0] is pointing to the address of the structure and I should use people[0]->name or (*people[0]).name to access the name?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL 4

int main(void) {
    typedef struct tagPerson {
        char name[12];
        int ID;
    } Person;

    #define LPPERSON Person*

    Person * people = calloc(sizeof(Person), TOTAL);
    strncpy(people[0].name, "Henry", 12);
    strncpy(people[1].name, "Jacob", 12);

    printf("sizeof(people)=%d\n", sizeof(people));
    printf("people[0].name=%s\n", people[0].name);
    printf("sizeof(people[0])=%d\n", sizeof(people[0]));
    printf("people[1].name=%s\n", people[1].name);
    printf("sizeof(people[1])=%d\n", sizeof(people[1]));

    free(people);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(people)=8

people[0].name=Henry
sizeof(people[0])=16

people[1].name=Jacob
sizeof(people[1])=16
```

Comment: You have switched the arguments in the call to  [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

Comment: Isn't calloc only return a pointer to the lowest byte in the allocated memory?

Comment: Your use of `strncpy()` is dangerous. (well, *every* use of strncpy() is dangerous ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`people` is a pointer to `Person`. `E1[E2]` is an array subscript operation, that is equal to `*((E1) + (E2))` [(6.5.2.1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf). Here `E1` must be pointer to T and `E2` must be of an integer type. Type of whole expression is simply T. In your case `E1` is a pointer to `Person`, so `people[0]` has type of `Person`, and access to fields is performed via `.` instead of `->`.

If you want to use arrow - you can do it in next way:

```
(people + 1)->name; /* the same as people[1].name */
```

Answer (score 1):

`Person * people` means that:

data type of `people` is `Person *`, i.e. `pointer` to `Person`.

and;

datatype of `*people` is `Person`, i.e. a `Person` data type. And similary, datatype of `*(people + index)` is also a `Person`.

And because, `people[index]` is internally converted into `*(people + index)`, the datatype of `people[index]` is `Person`- and NOT a`pointer to Person`.

Since `people[index]` is of datatype `Person`, and not a `pointer to Person`, you access its members using the `.` operator, and NOT the `->` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because people is an array of person structs, not pointers. If your array contained pointers, you would need to use the arrow notation. You can create structs without using pointers, and arrays of structs.

Comment: The variable `people` is not an array, but it points to memory that can be used as one.

Comment: That's true. It's also true of arrays in general, so I don't know how helpful the distinction is.